# instanceof

Tags: javascript

```
function F() { }
function G() { }
var p = {};
F.prototype = p;
G.prototype = p;
var f = new F();
var g = new G();

//alert(f instanceof F);   // returns true, все ясно
//alert(f instanceof G);   // returns true, почему так?? они ведь даже никак не связаны

//alert(g instanceof F);   // returns true, почему так??
//alert(g instanceof G);   // returns true, все ясно

F.prototype = {};
alert(f instanceof F);     // returns false, почему так??
g.__proto__ = {};
g instanceof G;            // returns false, почему так??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

всё дело в том, как работает оператор `instanceof` - он сравнивает прототип объекта со свойством prototype конструктора(а потом прототип прототипа со свойством prototype конструктора и т.д. пока не упрётся в null)

```
f instanceof F <==> f.__proto__ === F.prototype
```

т.о. у вас конструкторы `F` и `G` в свойстве `prototype` содержат ссылку на один и тот же объект, поэтому все объекты порождённые данными конструкторами с помощью `new` будут иметь прототипом тоже ссылку на этот объект, когда вы делаете:

```
F.prototype = {};
```

вы изменяете ссылку на другой объект, а объект `f` содеражит ссылку на старый прототип. в случае с

```
g.__proto__ = {};
```

тоже самое, но наоборот.

- [Основы и заблуждения насчет JavaScript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120193/)